# Generating compile_commands.json without generating build files

Tags: cmake

I'd like to generate a `compile_commands.json` file for use with the clangd language server. However, `EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS` only works for the make and ninja build systems. When building a project that uses a different build system it would be convenient to also be able to generate `compile_commands.json` files as if I was using make or ninja without actually generating any build files that interfere with the build system that I'm using to perform the build.

What is the most convenient way to do this with cmake?

Answer (score 1):

I think your only option here is to have a different build folder with Ninja or Makefile to generates the `compile_commands.json` and have a different build folder for your "actual" build.

The thing is, CMake is a generator, and it doesn't support mixed builds; and  in fact, it should not. If they do that, you will end up having random artifacts from different build systems inside the build folder that might eventually conflicts with each others.

That being said, you are aware that what you get in Ninja-based `compile_commands.json` is not going to be fully relevant to your "actual" build system that you want to use. I can see it being useful, but not the same for sure.